# Why use reflect api in flink hive shim

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm reading Flink hive connector code, find interface `HiveShim`, its have many implement class. but I find implement class use reflect API. why not import dependency, the code is so obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import multiple versions of hive library may cause dependency conflict.

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14588